# netbeans cannot open git-upload-pack

Tags: git, netbeans, push

today i have tried to upload changes to my git from work, so i can continue working at home. Just as usual. Until i found out i am not able to push changes anymore. I have checked to log file and found this

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.git.ui.repository.remote.SelectUriStep]: Cannot connect to https://github.com/someuser/someproject
java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1199)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1040)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1038)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1037)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:91)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1484)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1482)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1481)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.JDKHttpConnection.getResponseCode(JDKHttpConnection.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:475)
Caused: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://someuser@github.com/someuser/someproject
```

: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:309)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.ListRemoteObjectsCommand.runTransportCommand(ListRemoteObjectsCommand.java:74)
    Caused: org.netbeans.libs.git.GitException: https://someuser@github.com/someuser/someproject: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.TransportCommand.handleException(TransportCommand.java:261)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.ListRemoteObjectsCommand.runTransportCommand(ListRemoteObjectsCommand.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.TransportCommand.run(TransportCommand.java:191)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand$1.run(GitCommand.java:80)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand$1.run(GitCommand.java:77)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.jgit.commands.GitCommand.execute(GitCommand.java:77)
    at org.netbeans.libs.git.GitClient.listRemoteBranches(GitClient.java:916)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$36.call(GitClient.java:605)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$36.call(GitClient.java:601)
    at org.openide.util.NetworkSettings.suppressAuthenticationDialog(NetworkSettings.java:140)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker$1$1.call(GitClient.java:954)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker$1.call(GitClient.java:979)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethodIntern(GitClient.java:991)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:920)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.runMethod(GitClient.java:898)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient$CommandInvoker.access$400(GitClient.java:892)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitClient.listRemoteBranches(GitClient.java:601)
    [catch] at org.netbeans.modules.git.ui.repository.remote.SelectUriStep$2.perform(SelectUriStep.java:263)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.performIntern(GitProgressSupport.java:115)
    at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.run(GitProgressSupport.java:108)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
    WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.progress.spi.InternalHandle]: Cannot call progress on a task that was never started at org.netbeans.modules.git.client.GitProgressSupport.setProgressMessage(GitProgressSupport.java:281)

I found some similar errors on the internet, however most of them ware caused by SSL handshake exception or something similiar. It is different in this case and i cannot find the solution. CCan somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that you can access git successfully outside of NetBeans since the error shown above?

Comment: Yes. I can normally access it via web browser. Also push works at home as usually. It doesn't work in my workplace (but it did before). It must some software change, but i have no idea what in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of the work network (bad proxy address). As soon as i switched to my personal WiFi hotspot, it worked